# OAUTH / Azure Functions: Method to auth AAD user for endpoints that don't support service principals

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-functions

I've been leveraging Azure Function Apps to automate items in Azure.  I currently have working functions that connect to Microsoft Graph, Resource Explorer, KV etc. using service principal / OAUTH client credentials flow (inside the function app). To call my function app, I've implemented implicit flow.  While I'm not an expert at OAUTH, I am familiar enough now to get this configured and working.

However, there are Azure endpoints I need to use that don't support using a service principal token, they only support an actual AAD user requesting a token. Here's one that I want to run: [Create synchronizationJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/synchronization-synchronizationjob-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

If you look at the permissions section of the above link, you'll see that "application" is not supported.  I did test this in a function: I can run these endpoints in Graph Explorer fine (as myself), but they fail in the function when using a token linked to a service principal.

Since this new automation is going to be an Azure Function (and not an interactive user), I can't use the authorization code flow.  I need this service account's OAUTH to be non-interactive.

**TL;DR**

I can run the above endpoint in Azure's Graph Explorer just fine:

[Azure Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

since I'm authenticating as myself, and have a token generated based on my user ID.  But for automating using Azure Functions where I need to use this endpoint (which doesn't support OAUTH using an SP), I need some way to have a back-end AAD user auth and pull a token that can be used to run the endpoint.

Any help is welcome!  Feel free to tell me that I'm either missing something very basic, or not understanding a core principal here.

Comment: This is a bit of a common issue with some APIs. Since this is an endpoint on MS Graph API, you could try giving the appropriate directory admin role to the service principal and try running the request then. No guarantee that will work though :/

Comment: Yeah, tried that.  :(
Worked with Microsoft and they agreed that SP's are not currently supported. So I'm trying to see if there's an OAUTH flow that can potential handle this instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As juunas mentioned `no guarantee that will work though`, I test in my side and it seems doesn't work although I assigned "Global administrator" role to the service principal.

For your situation, you can request the access token in your function code and then use the access token to request the graph api.

Add the code like below in your function to get access token.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "client_id", "<your app client id>" },
    { "scope", "<scope>" },
    { "username", "<your user name>" },
    { "password", "<your password>" },
    { "grant_type", "password" },
};

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

var response = await client.PostAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your tenant id>/oauth2/v2.0/token", content);

var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var obj = JObject.Parse(responseString);
var accessToken = (string)obj["access_token"];
```

And then use the access token got above to request graph api.

Comment: This sample uses the ROPC flow which isn't really recommended and will not work if the user account has MFA for example. The more secure but more tedious approach is to use authorization code flow + refresh tokens.

Comment: @juunas - I agree with you that the ROPC flow isn't normally recommended, but it's probably my only option. The call to the problem endpoint is happening within my function app, and the user's front-end making the call to the azure function is an on-prem internal system that we control (not sure if it can even prompt the user for auth like the auth code flow).  Since these are all internal systems, MFA has already taken place for the user.
If I've already MFA'd the user to the app, and control the app, auth server (Azure) and API (Function App), am I still exposing anything by using ROPC?

Comment: @juunas To be clearer on the workflow: User uses ITSM tool (user already auth'd to ITSM.  ITSM calls Function App to do the needful.  Function app needs to run specific endpoints that can only be executed by a "user" rather than a service principal.
No idea if ITSM has the ability to perform the user redirects required in the authorization code flow.
* Disclaimer: I am in no way an OAUTH expert, but am trying to educate myself in this area.

Comment: @ScottFischer Yes, as juunas mentioned ROPC flow is not recommended. But I'm not sure if we can implement auth code flow in function, so I recommend you with ROPC flow. As far as I know, maybe we can implement auth code flow in function, but we need to set the function as a controller and to call another function, it is not simple. I don't know if we can do it success.

Comment: @ScottFischer For your situation to solve the problem of MFA, you can do one authorization outside the function app and get a refresh token, store the refresh token in azure storage or in function app D disk. When request the function, use the refresh token to get a new access token and a new refresh token. Then use the access token to request graph api and also store the new refresh token.....

Comment: @ScottFischer By the way, if you request the function frequently, you do not need to worry about the refresh token life time. But if you request the function occasionally, you need to refresh the refresh token periodically. You can use a timer trigger function to do it. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anA7Q.png) is the life time of refresh token.

Comment: @ScottFischer Did the user authenticate with Azure AD to the ITSM tool? If they did, you could acquire an access token for the user, and the function would be able to use on-behalf-of flow to get tokens for that user. Of course if you need to run the request as some specific user this doesn't help for that.

Comment: The approach with refresh tokens indeed requires a bootstrapping process where some component redirects the user to authenticate with authorization code flow and exchanges the code for the refresh token. This refresh token it then stores in e.g. Azure Key Vault. The Function can then get the refresh token from KV at any time and use it to get an access token and a new refresh token. Refresh tokens can expire, in which case the process would stop working and the user would have to bootstrap the process again. Pros and cons with all approaches :)

Comment: @junnas The ITSM tool is on-prem, so they are authenticated using AD, not AAD. ITSM would be issuing the call for the user.  You're correct - I would need to run the command as a specific service account (that had appropriate permissions), and not on behalf of the user (who doesn't have the permissions required).  That's a good train of thought though

Comment: Thanks everyone for your thoughts.  I think that for my specific use case, the ROPC flow makes sense.  I'll mark that as the answer.  Cheers!